# How to add semicolon at the end of a line using pattern from that line

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I am trying to find a way to add semicolon at the end of all lines that contain the word "transient" in them using **sed**.
This file is an hql that contains create statements of all tables in a database.
In order to run this hql on other cluster via beeline, I need to make some edits to this HQL before running it.

Input:

```
'transient_lastDdltime'='123456')
```

Expected output:

```
'transient_lastDdltime'='123456');
```

It will be really helpful if i can get a suggestion using sed or awk (not vim) please.

Comment: Note that questions about using UNIX tools that aren't unique to writing software are generally a better fit for our sister site [unix.se]. (There's a lot of grey area; "is it likely for someone to do this on the command line, as opposed to in a script?" is a good place to start in building a dividing line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sed '/transient/s/$/;/' file
```